# Netscaler SDX 11515 login failure after upgrade

Tags: load-balancer

I've got a makeshift lab scenario with an old SDX that came with 10.1 software. I'm new to these machines but have inherited the project and need to cope. I simply used the default *nsroot/nsroot* login and went for the upgrade.

When I upgraded the management service to 12.1, login via web GUI began to fail (*Unknown user and password*). Likely, I shouldn't have skipped the intermediate 11.1 release, and that might have broken something integral. I've tried rebooting the appliance and logging into SSH - no go. Is there anything else I could try?

To make matters worse, I've got only remote access to the Netscaler via management port, *not* the serial console.

Fortunately, there's a VPX instance running that we can use. It was deployed as 10.1 and upgraded to 11.1, then to 12.1 - same *nsroot/nsroot* login still working.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about servers are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Comment: @RonMaupin Erm - that Netscaler is a load-balancing appliance. Of course, with optional, paid support...

Comment: It claims to be an Application Delivery Server Appliance for cloud data centers.

Comment: @RonMaupin Well, it's called application delivery controller but I wouldn't call it a server in any way. The description on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citrix_ADC) is much better that at the Citrix site imho.

Comment: They must have a password recovery procedure

Comment: @RonTrunk Absolutely - the device is remote and I've got no access to the serial port, however.